# Rails Paperclip polymorphic styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip for attachments for multiple models using accepts_nested_attributes_for. Is there a way I can specify specific paperclip style options for each model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. I use single table inheritance (STI) on sites for handling Audio, Video, and Images via an Asset model.

```
# models/Asset.rb
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Asset has to exist as a model in order to provide inheritance
  # It can't just be a table in the db like in HABTM. 
end

# models/Audio.rb
class Audio < Asset # !note inheritance from Asset rather than AR!
  # I only ever need the original file
  has_attached_file :file
end

# models/Video.rb
class Video < Asset
  has_attached_file :file, 
    :styles => {
      :thumbnail => '180x180',
      :ipod => ['320x480', :mp4]
      },
    :processors => "video_thumbnail"
end

# models/Image.rb
class Image < Asset
  has_attached_file :file,
    :styles => {
      :medium => "300x300>", 
      :small => "150x150>",
      :thumb => "40x40>",
      :bigthumb => "60x60>"
    }
end
```

They all come into Rails as `:file`, but the controller (A/V/I) knows to save to the proper model. Just remember that all attributes for any of the forms of media need to be included in `Asset`: if video doesn't need captions but images do, then the caption attribute will be nil for `Video`. It won't complain.

Associations will also work fine if hooked up to the STI models. `User has_many :videos` will operate the same as you are using it now, just make sure you don't try to save to Asset directly.

```
  # controllers/images_controller.rb
  def create
    # params[:image][:file] ~= Image has_attached_file :file
    @upload = current_user.images.build(params[:image]) 
    # ...
  end
```

Lastly, since you do have an Asset model, you can still read directly from it if e.g. you want a list of the 20 most recent Assets. Also, this example isn't restricted to separating media types, it can be used for different kinds of the same thing as well: Avatar < Asset, Gallery < Asset, and so on.

Comment: Where do you define where the file gets saved? On the Asset model? Or is the Asset model blank? say: `:storage => :s3,
                    :bucket => Rails.application.config.aws_s3_bucket,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :path => ":class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"`

Comment: I just use the default and keep the Asset model blank, but I bet there's a way to have a default set in the Asset model. I haven't tried.

Answer (score 2):

A much [nicer](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/adding-polymorphic-image-styles-using-paperclip/) way can be, (if use are dealing with images):

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  has_attached_file :attachment, styles: lambda {
    |attachment| { 
      thumb: ( 
        attachment.instance.imageable_type.eql?("Product") ? ["300>", 'jpg'] :  ["200>", 'jpg']   
      ),
      medium: ( 
       ["500>", 'jpg']
      )
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: Is your answer really works? attachment.instance.imageable_type is nil

Comment: @ArtemAminov Yes it works.. as I am using it in one of my project.

Comment: maybe you can help me with my project, please see code here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901485/paperclip-polymorphic-styles)